# Place braces around page numbers

Tags: page-numbering, text-decorations

I'd like to have my page numbers go from this: 2 to this { 2 }. Basically, I just want to add some decoration to the page numbers throughout a book.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: One could redefine `\thepage`, but this would affect the way page numbers are printed everywhere. So a `footer` or `header` change is more appropiate

Comment: I'm using the regular book...

Answer (score 3):

With the `fancyhdr` package you can define what is displayed in the header and footer. Getting your desired page numbers would require you to define

```
\fancyfoot[FC]{\{ \thepage \}}
```

in your preamble

EDIT: The F is not needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's `F` for?

Comment: @egreg, thank you. The F is actually not needed. I don't know why I've always been using it.

Comment: That causes an error for me; I'll have to troubleshoot this a bit. Do I need to use \pagestyle{fancy} for this?